# How to make aliases automatically work at startup?

Tags: bash, git-bash, aliases

I have my aliases in ~/.bash_aliases

I used to run ubuntu and these aliases automatically worked from startup.

Now when I switched to windows and started to use Git Bash, I have to use

```sh
source ~/.bash_aliases
```

or

```sh
. ~/.bash_aliases
```

to get them to be recognized by the bash

How can I get them to work without using this command every time I open bash?

I think it's something i have to do in the ~/.bashrc

Comment: Yes, put the `source` line in your .bashrc file

Comment: I have `if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then . ~/.bash_aliases ; fi` in my `~/.bashrc` .

Comment: I like to use ```~/.profile``` for using aliases or self defined functions and simply create a softlink from the doted rc file to my desired ```.profile```. And if i dont wanna load a doted rc file i simply softlinking it to ```/dev/null```. Thats what i am making with unwanted log files on a Rasperry Pi for example. I tried then this with unwanted doted history files in home folder and thats work too. So ```/dev/null``` is my friend.

Answer (score 1):

There are various files which get loaded if they exists on startup depending on how it is invoked.

### Invoked as a login shell

When Bash is invoked as an interactive login shell, or as a non-interactive shell with the --login option, it first reads and executes commands from the file /etc/profile, if that file exists. After reading that file, it looks for ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, and ~/.profile, in that order, and reads and executes commands from the first one that exists and is readable. The --noprofile option may be used when the shell is started to inhibit this behavior.

When an interactive login shell exits, or a non-interactive login shell executes the exit builtin command, Bash reads and executes commands from the file ~/.bash_logout, if it exists.

### Invoked as an interactive non-login shell

When an interactive shell that is not a login shell is started, Bash reads and executes commands from ~/.bashrc, if that file exists. This may be inhibited by using the --norc option. The --rcfile file option will force Bash to read and execute commands from file instead of ~/.bashrc.

So, typically, your ~/.bash_profile contains the line

if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then . ~/.bashrc; fi
after (or before) any login-specific initializations.

You can source your `bash_aliases` file from within your `.bashrc` file by adding

```
[ -f ~/.bash_aliases ] && . ~/.bash_aliases
```

Also [this is helpful post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/51036/what-is-the-difference-between-bash-profile-and-bashrc) to understand the difference between `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile`

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you're right! To configure bash aliases, you can put them in `.bashrc` file in your home directory. For instance:

```sh
cd
echo alias ll=\'ls -ltrh\' >> .bashrc
```

Next, you need to either source this file (i.e. run source `.bashrc`) or restart to your terminal to take this changes into effect.

If you have an aliases.sh file (an equivalent for `.bashrc` file) available in `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_\etc\profile.d\aliases.sh` or under `C:\Program Files\Git\etc\profile.d\aliases.sh`, you can make use of that file too.

Answer (score 0):

Your .bashrc gets sourced by bash as you login or open a new bash shell.
Anything you source within your .bashrc - will also get sourced.

So in your case placing

`[ -f ~/.bash_aliases ] && . ~/.bash_aliases`

within your .bashrc , should do the trick.